# Как подгрузить фото с instagram на свой сайт

Tags: php, instagram-api

Как можно подгрузить последние фото в определенном количестве с Instagram на свой сайт, используя например теги img для их отображения.

Answer (score 1):

Проще всего - взяв готовый виджет на чистом php. Например такой: http://inwidget.ru/

Там есть подробная документация, мобильная адаптация и все необходимые для работы функции.

Помимо этого под различные CMS существуют готовые плагины/модули. Если у вас какая-нибудь joomla/wordpress можете посмотреть в их каталоге расширений плагин.

Если же хочется "посложнее", то вот пара проектов на GIT:

- https://github.com/postaddictme/instagram-php-scraper
- https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API

Ну и если хотите по хардкору писать своё с нуля, то вот документация: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/

Comment: спасибо, мне необходимо установить отображение на самописе, потом все это установить на yii 2, чтож буду разбираться с api facebook'a

Comment: @Houckz https://github.com/kmarenov/yii2-instagram-widget